# Using Wordpress passwords from wp_users database table via PhoneGap Mobile App and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phonegap

I tried doing some search for this but I am not getting satisfied with the results I am getting.

I am developing a mobile application (using Adobe Phone Gap and PHP) with a login page that is running a script that will access the wp_users table. I noticed the passwords are in an encrypted format which begins in $P$XXXXXXXX/XX/

is there a way that I can use that table in order for me to do the login process on my mobile app?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this should be possible. You don't need to decrypt the user's password.  In fact, no one but the user should know the password. Please read this article: http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/integrate-your-mobile-app-with-wordpress-users-table/ It might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for this, so lets say i have a form that will send out on submit a request if the user and pass matches (simple login) lets say user is admin and pass is 654321, it'll automatically authenticate that? (Sorry didn't have that much experience)

Comment: Note that you do need to understand the difference between *encrypted* and *hashed*.  The passwords here are hashed, not encrypted.

Comment: thanks @Michael-sqlbot so I need to run a decoder correct?
I also read about REST APIs is that another option?

Comment: Noooo, exactly not that.  There is no "decoder."  As I say, familiarize yourself with hashed passwords.  (Also, read the Wordpress source.)  Hashing, unlike encryption, is a non-reversible process.  Given pasword x and hash y, you hash password x and if you get y then the password matches.  You can compare a password to a hash, but you cannot extract a password from a hash.  Read about, and understand, [cryptographic hash functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) before proceeding.  REST is a bit irrelevant until you have a clear objective in view.

Comment: Hhaha! Oh boy pardon my newbiishness, i tried working on with the suggestions you gave me and it is now working! I cam across REST api as well managed to give it a try using the JSON API plugin and wow that was easy! Also the client has a developer account on their Memberpress which also has the REST api thing, that is wonderful! Thanks so much! I learned a lot!